# Power BI REST Admin - Datasets GetDatasourcesAsAdmin return DMTS_UserNotFoundInADGraphError

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-rest-api

I got this DMTS_UserNotFoundInADGraphError error when using [Power BI REST Admin - Datasets GetDatasourcesAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets-get-datasources-as-admin#datasource) API to get datasources.

Here is the full error

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":"DMTS_UserNotFoundInADGraphError",
        "pbi.error":{
            "code":"DMTS_UserNotFoundInADGraphError",
            "parameters":{},
            "details":[],
            "exceptionCulprit":1
        }
    }
}
```

I tried Googling about this and found nothing.
Does anyone know what is this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when trying to run the API call against a dataset and after further investigation found the dataset to have come from a Personal Workspace with a status of "deleted".

Looks like the user has left and been deleted from AD / Entra.